# VS Code: rubocop/linting change how many lines are underlined

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, rubocop

I'm looking to find a way to change which lines of my code are underlined when a methed or class rule is violated. i.e. I just want the line `class WhateverClass < ApplicationRecord`
to be underlined with the error rather than every line in the class being underlined.

I'm working on an older rails app and, unsurprisingly, just about every class and method has too many lines or too great a complexity. In my VIM setup this isn't an issue (visually) because just the `class` or `def` line will be underlined. In VS Code every line is underlined which makes the file hard to read and other violations impossible to find.

Is there a way to change this, or should I just grab another extension?

I'm using the Ruby extension by Peng Lv, here is my my `settings.json`:

```json
{
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "diffEditor.renderSideBySide": false,
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "editor.renderWhitespace": "trailing",
    "editor.fontFamily": "'Cascadia Code PL', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "editor.inlineHints.fontFamily": "'Cascadia Code PL', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    "ruby.useBundler": true,
    "ruby.useLanguageServer": true,
    "ruby.lint": {
        "rubocop": {
            "useBundler": true
          }
    },
    "ruby.format": "rubocop",
    "ruby.codeCompletion": "rcodetools"
}
```

Comment: Re: ".. older rails app .. just about every class and method has [an offence]" As a workaround, you might try the "todo file workflow". You can generate a todo file with `--auto-gen-config`.